# Making rivers with higher Strahler/stream order wider in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, visualisation, watershed, rivers

I have a river network and the Strahler order of all rivers in it. Now I would like to create a map similar to this one http://www.hydrosheds.org/, i.e. with rivers of a higher Strahler order being wider than those with a lower Strahler order.

How can I perform that kind of analyses?

Comment: Is the Strahler order of each river stored in a field?

Comment: No, it is just a raster file including the Strahler orders of the complete catchment/watershed. My workaround atm is to seperately calculate the river channel for every Strahler order and assign different width to them. That works, but there is probably an easier way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If the order is stored in the field and the field type is integer, you can simply right-click he layer in the table of content go to `Style -> Width -> Select the field that has Stream Order`.

[image]

But if the field type is `string` type as in the above example, then you need to convert it to `integer` using the expression

`to_int("Field_Name" )`

Here is a sample output for only two orders:

[image]